# Python division by zero error during for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, for-loop, python-requests

I'm trying to get the following loop for:

```
for index, xi in enumerate(total_elements['Acquisti']):
        if index==0:

            rim_finale['Rimanenza Finale'][index]=xi-(xi/total_quantita['Acquisti'][index])*total_utilizzato['Utilizzato'][index]

        else:
            rim_finale['Rimanenza Finale'][index]=(rim_iniziale['Rimanenza Iniziale'][index]+xi)-((rim_iniziale['Rimanenza Iniziale'][index]+xi)/
            (delta_quant['delta'][index-1]+delta_quant['delta'][index]))*total_utilizzato['Utilizzato'][index]
```

Starting from the first amount:

```
xi-(xi/total_quantita['Acquisti'][index])*total_utilizzato['Utilizzato'][index]
```

If `total_quantita` is equal to zero, the result must be `xi`

In the secondo case:

```
((rim_iniziale['Rimanenza Iniziale'][index]+xi)/
                (delta_quant['delta'][index-1]+delta_quant['delta'][index])
```

if `delta_quant['delta'][index-1]+delta_quant['delta'][index]`is equal to zero, the result of equanto must be `(rim_iniziale['Rimanenza Iniziale'][index]+xi)`

How could overcome that problem?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what is in the data that you are dividing by.

Comment: You are dividing in a couple of places - could your total-quantity be zero for some index? or maybe the sum of some of the delta-quant? How you overcome this will depend on what you want to have happen in those cases. To start with maybe inspect your data and see that you have understood how your algorithm should handle those cases.

Comment: I have edited my answer, I hope that now is exaustive

Comment: It is vital that you provide a (small, possibly simplified) code snippet that can reproduce the error and that you tell us what behavior you expect.

Comment: You have provided some clear rules that can be translated directly to code. For example, "If ``total_quantita`` is equal to zero, the result must be ``xi``"  is literally ``if total_quantita == 0: result = xi``. The only adjustment for your code would be that ``rim_finale['Rimanenza Finale'][index]`` is actually ``rim_finale['Rimanenza Finale'][index]``. What specific problem do you have translating these rules into code?